# Partial derivatives in multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was doing some practice problems and everything was going great till I saw this question out of the ordinary: 
$$ f(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(xy)^n \qquad \left|xy\right| < 1 $$
Any thoughts on how to do this?

I know that the general formula should be something like this:
Differentiate with respect to $x$: $nx^{n-1}y^n$

But this whole summation thing really confuses me as I am not 100% sure what to do.

Comment: Just sun the series first as in then hint and the find the derivative.

Comment: would it be converge to 1/(1-xy) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This sum is a geometric series.